# Chrome / Safari not filling 100% height/width of flex parent

Tags: html, css

Can you see the white space? How can I remove it?

```
demo: http://jsfiddle.net/49c1kzxv/
```

[image]

Some other issue with element has border inside a Flexbox:
https://www.highconcrete.com/
[image]

[image]

Comment: you can put the html on one line -> `<div class="item">......<div class="item">......`

Comment: I've tried, but it does not work :D You can try here: http://jsfiddle.net/49c1kzxv/

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code you've provided. Using Chrome and Firefox, there are no white borders / gaps.